# StringBuffer behaviour

Tags: java, stringbuffer

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        TestMathRandom x = new Test();
         StringBuffer a = new StringBuffer ("A");
         StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer ("B");
         x.operate (a,b);
         System.out.println(a + "," +b);
    }

    void operate (StringBuffer x, StringBuffer y) {
         x.append(y);
         y = x;

    }
}
```

Ans is AB,B Please tell me why value of b is unchanged.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Answer (score 1):

You are passing values of the variables x and y, not a reference to them. So the changed made inside the operate function are useless, follow the link provided as a comment to your post to understand better ;)

Answer (score 0):

Passing StringBuffer in parameter of method operate is `passbyvalue`. In this type, the value of variable is just copied into the temp variable defined in method's parameter. Means in your example value of both a and b are just copied in `x` and `y`. Here value of `a` got changed but `b` didn't.
Its obvious. Here value of `b` didnt change because `y` is the mirror copy of `b`. But `append` function works with actual value. It takes reference of `x` and append the `y` with it and ultimately it shows change at `a`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because in Java arguments are passed by value. So y = x just changes local var y value in operate method.